# Wildcards generic in Kotlin for parameter

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an abstract class using for listen api callback like below. ApiRs is a parent object that every API response object inherit from it

```
abstract class ApiCallback<in T : ApiRs> {

    open fun onSucceed(apiRsModel: T) {}

    open fun onFailed(code: Int,
                      message: String) {
    }
}
```

and i also write a function to check network status before request api, if network is not connected, then it will trigger `onFailed`

```
fun isNetworkAvailable(apiCallback: ApiCallback<ApiRs>?,
                           context: Context): Boolean{
        val connectivityManager = context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo

        // device network unreachable
        if (networkInfo == null
                || !networkInfo.isConnected) {
            // callback with network error
            apiCallback?.onFailed(code, message)
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
```

the parameter type `ApiCallback<ApiRs>?` actually i want to write it like `ApiCallback<? extends ApiRs>?`, but Kotlin has no wildcard. If i replace the generic to `ApiCallback<out ApiRs>?`, it will show an error

> Projection is conflicting with variance of the corresponding type parameter of ApiCallback

Is there any way to fix it? or just i have wrong concept of Kotlin generic?

---

2017/09/18 update - The right way is :

Method :

```
fun <T : ApiRs> isNetworkAvailable(apiCallback: ApiCallback<T>?,
                                       context: Context): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager = context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo

        // device network unreachable
        if (networkInfo == null
                || !networkInfo.isConnected) {
            // callback with network error
            callbackWithFailed(
                    apiCallback,
                    ApiError.API_ERROR_CODE_0,
                    context.getString(R.string.api_error_code_0))
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
```

Comment: `ApiCallback<out ApiRs>` this will take any type of `ApiRs`. See star-projections https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections

Comment: Does not work, when i using `ApiCallback<out ApiRs>`, than the warning above will show

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski Is right. Every API extending ApiRs will be accepted, but without another cast will only have the features your ApiRs class provides.

Comment: OK i know what you guys mean, change `ApiCallback<ApiRs>?` to `ApiCallback<*>?` right?

Comment: No. `ApiCallback<*>` is same as `ApiCallback<Any>` you need setting upper limit of the type `ApiCallback<out SpecificType>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand that you want to accept `apiCallback: ApiCallback<ApiRs>?` in your method in a way that the generic type of `ApiCallback` can be `ApiRs` itself or any of its subtypes. Instead of wildcards, Kotlin has [upper bounds](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-constraints). You can declare the function like this:

```
fun <T: ApiRs> isNetworkAvailable(apiCallback: ApiCallback<T>?,
                       context: Context)
```

Comment: Thanks! your solution very make sense!