# Kotlin generic parameter using in function

Tags: android, kotlin

i got solution of this question: [Wildcards generic in Kotlin for parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265621/wildcards-generic-in-kotlin-for-parameter), but now i have other question which still related to kotlin generic

I have an abstract class using for listen api callback like below. ApiRs is a parent object that every API response object inherit from it

```
abstract class ApiCallback<in T : ApiRs> {

    open fun onSucceed(apiRsModel: T) {}

    open fun onFailed(code: Int,
                      message: String) {
    }
}
```

this time i write a function to handle api succeed with Retrofit2, than check something and callback to UI, here is my function:

```
fun <T : ApiRs> callbackWithSucceed(apiCallback: ApiCallback<T>?,
                                        context: Context,
                                        response: Response<out ApiRs>?) {
        // unexpected error
        if (response == null) {
            encounterUnexpectedError(apiCallback, context, null)
            return
        }

        // check http
        val httpSucceed = response.code() == CODE_HTTP_SUCCEED
                && response.isSuccessful
                && response.body() != null
        if (!httpSucceed) {
            // HTTP response with error
            callbackWithFailed(
                    apiCallback,
                    response.code(),
                    response.message())
            return
        }

        apiCallback?.onSucceed(response.body()!!)
    }
}
```

`response` is Retrofit2 class, which contains my API response model (body) and every response model are inherit ApiRs, my goal is pass the model to the abstract class using this way `apiCallback?.onSucceed(response.body()!!)` but it will show an error

> Type mismatch, required T? but Found ApiRs?

Sorry about i have bad concept of generic. I think function `open fun onSucceed(apiRsModel: T) {}` T should inherit ApiRs because i defined in class, so i cannot understand why error message shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `response: Response<out ApiRs>?` has to be `response: Response<out T>?`, then the error should be gone.

The type of `T` which will be passed to the method `onSuccess` must match the generic type of the `apiCallback` parameter, which isn't `<ApiRs>` but `<T>`.

Comment: You're welcome. Next time you can also reuse the old question